# Change line ending character on Mac

Tags: macos, vim

I got a new Mac and hammered out some code in Vim. When I viewed the git diff the code I changed had a "^M" after each line. It seems like my new mac is using windows line ending character for some reason. This is not an issue with my text editor because this occurs in both [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) and Vim.

I cannot find any way to edit this in my system preferences and I am not sure where to go from here. It seems like every thread on Stack Overflow addressing this issue either simply offers an explanation of how line endings work or suggest using some third-party service to convert the line endings in a file. I want to know how to change the line endings my Mac inserts.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format

Answer (score 0):

Vim attempts to use the existing line endings for files. To set the line endings to Unix style explicitly, use

```
:set fileformat=unix
:w
```

See `:help fileformat` for further information. (Note that the Vim help may refer to "mac" style line endings, which refers to Classic Mac OS before 10.x. Mac OS X has always used Unix style line endings.)

Comment: This does not work for me. Vim still uses ^M linefeed character. Again, I think this is an issue with my Mac, not Vim. The same thing occurs when I use Sublime Texr

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4: Perhaps when Git shows you the diff, it is showing you the ^M because that exists in the original copy and *not* your modified copy.

Comment: Try a quick test.  put the string "set fileformat=unix" into your ~/.vimrc.  Then create a new file test.txt with a line like "I like beer".  Add & commit into git.  Then change the line to "I like whiskey".  Then do another diff and see if it is working.